# How do I export the history from the Windows command line to a text file?

Tags: windows, command-line, history, textfiles

How do I export the history from the Windows command line to a text file?

I think you can do it in Linux as something like "history >filename.txt", but how do you do it in Windows? I'm a [geneticist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneticist), and I want a record of exactly what programs I've run for my lab book.

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [`doskey`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/doskey.mspx?mfr=true) command to do this:

```
doskey /HISTORY > history.txt
```

Comment: doskey is not a command, it is external utility.

Comment: @Andrejs, actually its built into `cmd.exe`.  See the [Wikipedia article](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/DOSKey): *In current Windows NT-based operating systems DOSKey's functionality is built into cmd.exe, although the DOSKey command is still used to change its operation.*

Comment: seems i need to include the doskey bit?

Comment: also, is there a way i can get it to include information printed to the screen as well?

Comment: To see it on the screen, use just `doskey /history`

Comment: thanks but, no i mean i need that info printed to a file

Comment: @Bec, I guess I'm not quite understanding what you're asking for.  My original answer will output the command line's history to the file *history.txt*, what exactly do you mean by "printed to a file"?

Comment: ah yeah that worked ok, but only for commands i'd typed, info printed to screen from scripts etc. not included. guess i should just adapt my script to make a log.txt file but would be handy to know for when using someone else's script which i'm less able to adapt

Comment: You mean you want to save the command history AND the console output?

Comment: @heavyd: Thanks for update, I was not aware of that.

Comment: anyway to get complete history, not the one executed in the current window/cmd. ?

Comment: @coding_idiot the history is not saved, so no there is no way to get more than just the current window

Answer (score 0):

[clink](https://code.google.com/p/clink/) provides features that are similar to GNU readline and bash. In addition to `history`, you get something that's very similar to the navigational power that you get in Unix.

Answer (score -1):

To export the history, I was able to simply right click the window, click "select all" then CTRL-C to copy.  I then CTRL-P pasted into a text editor.

You'll want to max out the screen buffer height to 9999 when you start your session because you'll only be able to copy text that's showing in the buffer.  You set the screen buffer height by right clicking the title bar of the cmd window, select properties, click the layout tab.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP want's to copy the command history not the command output (screen contents)